# Updating Stripe accounts returns "Error: Stripe: "id" must be a string, but got: object"

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am trying to update a Stripe account to add an external account token to be charged later as shown in the example [here.](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/updating-accounts)

```
var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxx"),    
    knex   = require("knex")(config);

router.post("/paymentcardinfo",middleware.isLoggedIn,function(req,res){
      knex("users.stripe").select("stripe_id_key")
      .then((stripeID) => {
          stripeID = stripeID[0].stripe_id_key;
          console.log("My Stripe ID: "stripeID);
          console.log("stripeID var type:", typeof stripeID);
          stripe.accounts.update({
            stripeID,
            external_account: req.body.stripeToken,
        }, function(err,acct) {
          if(err){
            console.log(err);
          } else {
          console.log("SUCCESS ********",acct);
      // asynchronously called
        }})
      })
      .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
          res.redirect("/paymentcardinfo")
      });
    });
```

Which returns the following

```
     My Stripe ID:  acct_xxxxxxxxxxxxx
     stripeID var type:  string
    [Error: Stripe: "id" must be a string, but got: object (on API request to `POST /accounts/{id}`)]
```

where acct_xxxxxxxxxxx is the user's stored account ID. Based on the first console.log value, it would appear that stripeID is a string and not an object, which makes me unsure of how to proceed with this error.

Comment: remove this `var` keyword here: `var stripeID = stripeID[0].stripe_id_key;`

Comment: Thanks! I accidentally added that when changing variable names. Unfortunately, this still results in the same issue even when var is removed.

Comment: were you able to figure out the solution?  I am seeing this problem as well

Comment: @ShawnVarughese Yes. The stripe account id should be a string, not an object. I will answer the question to show a thorough example.

Comment: I have edited the answer for better clarity. This currently works on my platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the documentation specifies

```
 stripe.accounts.update({
  {CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID},
  metadata: {internal_id: 42},
}).then(function(acct) {
  // asynchronously called
});`
```

The following worked for me

```
stripe.accounts.update(
           CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID,
           {
            metadata: {internal_id:42},
          }
          ).then((account) => {
         // response to successful action
```

Comment: by adding "{" giving me syntex error :( i am facing the same issue